# Android dropbox sdk logout feature error

Tags: android, logout, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox android sdk to integrate dropbox with my app and I want to logout from dropbox from my Application.  From official documentation and dropbox forums the  only way to logout is to call `unlink()` on the dropbox session and clear your access token and secret from `SharedPreference`.

```
mApi.getSession().unlink();
//clear dropbox accesstoken and secret keys from SharedPreference
clearKeys();
```

Well the above call is not doing anything. When I try to login later

```
AppKeyPair appKeyPair   =   new AppKeyPair(AppConstants.DROPBOX_API_KEY,AppConstants.DROPBOX_API_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session;
session             =   new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
```

login screen is not getting shown, instead, the screen where api asks user permission to access a folder to dropbox (which normally shows after login screen) is shown instead.  Is there any way to logout from dropbox?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Sadly no. But it seems a bug on their part. I have seen other apps in market with same issue

Comment: Thanks for the update! Will have to proceed this way, then.

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when the application reaches `onResume()` function. Even if you are logged out, the dropbox api asks the browser to login, and it responds with keys. It seems the browser had cached the login. Try to clear web browser cache when calling logout function.

Comment: It works only when browser is used to login to the website.. If user has dropbox app in his device, clearing browser cache won't help.. Also I can't make user clear browser cache every time user logout from dropbox in my app..

Answer (score 0):

Because the unlink() call is purely client side work, it is not equal to unlink th e application with user account which you can do on Web under the "settings" page.

Here is the code snippet

```
@Override
public boolean isLinked() {
    return (oauth1AccessToken != null) || (oauth2AccessToken != null);
}

@Override
public void unlink() {
    oauth1AccessToken = null;
    oauth2AccessToken = null;
}
```